# Openshift nodejs mysql query crashes

Tags: mysql, node.js, openshift

I recently moved my app from localhost to openshift. The issue is when I try to get stuff from mysql database it throws an error.

```
/var/lib/openshift/55ace15350044671b700010b/app-root/runtime/repo/server.js:40
                                        if (err) throw err;
                                                       ^
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
    at errnoException (dns.js:37:11)
    at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:124:16)
```

Query:

```
mysqlConnection.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ' + "'" + json["email"] + "'", function (err, rows, fields) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    if (rows.length !== 0) {
                        if (bcrypt.compareSync(json["password"], decoder.write(rows[0].password))) {
                            ws.send("Password correct");
                        } else {
                            ws.send("Login password wrong");
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        ws.send('Invalid email');
                        console.log("Invalid email || no rows");
                    }});
```

Mysql connection initialization:

```
var mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({ //connect to mysql database
  host     : 'mysql://$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT/',
  user     : 'admin5x6cGHA',
  password : '************',
  database : 'dibsserver'
 ,debug    :  true
});
```

Comment: The DNS says can't find your host. Can't help you further, since the host is not specified in the posted code.

Comment: As an aside, I hope that `json["email"]` isn't passed in directly from an external source, otherwise you have just introduced a possible SQL injection vector.

Comment: Yup, I have no idea how to prevent this. Any ideas or material would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the quick answer: replace this line

```
 host     : 'mysql://$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT/',
```

by

```
 host     : 'mysql://' + process.env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST + ':' + process.env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT + '/',
```

For a little longer one:

In Node.JS, you can use process.env supper global to access environment variables.